# Data returned as null when taking a picture

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to set the thumbnail of the picture taken to the scr of an ImageButton. The following code works fine with taking the picture and storing it in the gallery but the "Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");" returns null.
Can anyone please explain why?

```
private void openCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.i("Camera log", "Failed:" + ex.toString());
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        cameraBtn.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        galleryAddPic();
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer `photoFile` object, which contain captured image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` you have to get the photo from this URL.

Example:

```
if(photoFile!=null){
 BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = null;
 bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getPath(), bmOptions);
 }
 else{
 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        cameraBtn.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        galleryAddPic();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Miguel. By adding 'getPath()' to the decodeFile(photoFile, bmOptions) in your answer, it was solved. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please explain why?

You provided `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Your image should be stored at the location you specified. If you do *not* provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, *then* `extras.get("data")` should have your `Bitmap` (at least if the camera app your app winds up using does not have bugs).